# 2 Header Rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

```
Extra Information      Details              VALUES
------------------     -------------------- --------
Academic Rank          Academic Rank        Professor    
Academic Rank          Effective Start Date 01-JAN-2017
Academic Rank          Effective End Date   02-JAN-2018
Academic Rank          Next Academic Rank   Master
Alien Income Forecast  Income_code          P
Alien Income Forecast  Amount               10000
Alien Income Forecast  Year                 2017
Passport Details       COUNTRY              US
Passport Details       PASSPORT_NUMBER      1XX
Passport Details       ISSUE_DATE           01-JAN-2017
Passport Details       EXPIRE_DATE          02-JAN-2018
```

I was hoping to format it in SQL and make it look like this:

```
Academic Rank                                                                   Alien Income Forecast       Passport Details
------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------------------------    ------------------------------------------------
Academic Rank   Effective Start Date    Effective End Date  Next Academic Rank  Income_code Amount  Year    COUNTRY PASSPORT_NUMBER ISSUE_DATE  EXPIRE_DATE
-------------   --------------------    ------------------  ------------------  ----------  ------  ----    ------  --------------- ----------  ------------
Professor       01-JAN-2017             02-JAN-2018         Master              P           10000   2017    US      1XX             01-JAN-2017 02-JAN-2018
```

Its something like a Merge Cell in Excel wherein i have 2 headers (Main Header and some Sub Headers) to present the data. 
I think it's not possible, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Do you know all the values of interest for `Extra Information` and `Details` columns?

Comment: @BSamedi, No, its quite a lot and there can be more values added to it.

Comment: It is possible to use the PIVOT clause but in this case you will need to use dynamic SQL because of the unknown number of potential headers.